# Are we able to position the y axis in the center of the x axis?

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, ngx-charts

[image]I'm trying to plot a chart as shown in the screen capture and I would like to shift the y-axis to the center of the x axis using existing charting fw like chart.js. Done a search but can't really find any answers.
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWIOX.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code on what you have tried.

Comment: I used a demo line chart. Possible values for position of axis are : 'top', 'left', 'bottom', 'right'. There is no config to set it to the center so I'm asking if anyone has experience to centre it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `position` option in the scale config and set it to `'center'` like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        position: 'center'
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```